# Why tolerance = 9999 doesn't work?

Tags: luatex, line-breaking

I expect if I set `\tolerance = 9999` there will be no overfull boxes. However, I have a case where changing the tolerance value has no effect at all. Moreover, you can visually see where would be a good place to break the line, but LuaTeX doesn't do it. Is it a bug in LuaTeX?

Here is an example (sorry for a lot of non-English text):

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, paper = B5]{scrbook}

\usepackage[babelshorthands = true]{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{lualatex-math}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{luacode}

\setmainfont{Erewhon}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Erewhon}
\setmathfont{Erewhon Math}

\KOMAoptions{BCOR = 5mm, DIV = 14}

\begin{luacode}
    function PrintShipoutBox()
        local soBox = tex.getbox("ShipoutBox")
        -- local nodetree = require('nodetree')
        -- nodetree.print(soBox)
    end
\end{luacode}
\AddToHook{shipout/before}{\directlua{PrintShipoutBox()}}

\tolerance = 9999

\begin{document}

\begin{floatingfigure}[l]{43mm}
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[black!10] (0,0) rectangle (43mm, 74mm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{floatingfigure}

Возьмём какое"=нибудь событие~— назовём его событием $O$~— в качестве начала отсчёта времени и
пространственных координат. Другими словами, в четырёхмерной системе координат, на осях которой
откладываются $x$, $y$, $z$ и $t$, мировая точка события $O$ будет началом координат. Посмотрим
теперь, в каком отношении к данному событию $O$ находятся все остальные события. Для наглядности мы
будем рассматривать только одну пространственную координату и время, откладывая их на двух осях
(рис.~2). Прямолинейное равномерное движение частицы, проходящей точку $x = 0$ при $t = 0$,
изобразится прямой линией, проходящей через $O$ и наклонённой к оси $t$ под углом, тангенс которого
равен скорости частицы. Поскольку наибольшая возможная скорость равна $c$, то существует наибольший
угол, который может образовывать эта прямая с осью $t$. На рис.~2 изображены две прямые,
изображающие распространение двух сигналов (со скоростью света) в противоположных направлениях,
проходящих через событие $O$ (т.~е. проходящих $x = 0$ при $t = 0$). Все ли\-нии, изображающие
движения частиц, могут лежать только внутри областей $aOc$ и $dOb$. На прямых $ab$ и $cd$, очевидно,
$x = \pm ct$. Рассмотрим сначала события, мировые точки которых лежат внутри области $aOc$. Легко
сообразить, что во всех точках этой области $c^2t^2 - x^2 > 0$. Другими словами, интервалы между
любым событием этой области и событием $O$~— времениподобные. В этой области $t > 0$, т.е. все
события этой области происходят «после» события $O$. Но два события, разделённых времениподобным
интервалом, ни в какой системе отсчёта не могут происходить одновременно. Следовательно, нельзя
выбрать и никакой системы отсчёта, где бы какое"=нибудь из событий области $aOc$ происходило «до»
события $O$, т.е. когда было бы $t < 0$. Таким образом, все события области $aOc$ являются будущими
по отношению к $O$, и притом во всех системах отсчёта. Эту область можно поэтому назвать «абсолютно
будущей» по отношению к событию $O$.

\end{document}
```

A fragment from the output:
[image]

You can see in the example that I even specified the hyphenation point for `ли\-нии`, yet it sticks out. If you uncomment lines in `PrintShipoutBox`, you can check the generated node tree. I don't see anything suspicious there. Here is near the first protruding `t = 0`:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: breaks fine for me, but I'm using the development version of luaotfload. polyglossia forces the harfbuzz renderer, and this can affect hyphenation. You could try if it helps to switch to the node renderer instead.

Comment: It seems a LuaTeX problem; if I compile with XeLaTeX (removing the LuaTeX specific bits), I get no overfull box, even with `\tolerane=2000`.

Comment: BTW even with `\tolerance=9999` one can easily get overfull boxes; to be more sure of not getting them you can use something like `\emergencystretch=\maxdimen` (or `=\hsize` or any large enough value, maybe a couple of inches for typical page dimensions would be more than enough). Of course, even this is no help if you have a single unbreakable box longer than the width of a line.

Comment: This is caused by https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/175 which is worked around in luaotfload's development version.

Comment: Thanks guys. How do I change the shaping engine then? I tried `[Renderer = OpenType]`, it has no effect.

Comment: I also downloaded the latest LuaTeX from https://serveur-svn.lri.fr/svn/modhel/luatex/trunk. I compiled it with `./build.sh --luahb`, ran `sudo fmtutil-sys --all`. I still have the same issue with line breaks. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I checked the source code at https://serveur-svn.lri.fr/svn/modhel/luatex/trunk, it seems like the patch https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-luatex/2021-February/006448.html wasn't submitted. I checked the `branches/experimental` branch, it's the same.

Comment: @facetus The [luatex team decided not to merge it yet](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-luatex/2021-February/006450.html). You can use the [development version of luaotfload](https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/tree/dev) to avoid the issue for the time being.

Comment: I wonder why they consider it a corner case. I have a quite regular TeX document with a quite regular `texlive` installation.

Comment: I tried this in OpTeX (LuaTeX without hb) and it works. The font is loaded as `[Erewhon-Regular]:+tlig; at 10.95pt`.

Comment: Yes, the problem is observed only in the hb engine. As far as I understand, luahbtex has a more complicated algorithm for dealing with the discretionary nodes (i.e. places where a hyphen can happen). It has something to do with kerning and ligatures. So overall, when it works, you may expect better results than in non-hb luatex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Marcel Krüger for pointing to [issue 175](https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/175) in `luaotfload`. The issue thread mentions a patch to luatex, you should ignore it. Here is what you should do if you experience this issue.

First, get the `dev` branch of `luaotfload`:

```
git clone -b dev https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload.git
```

Then copy `.lua` files from there to your TeX installation. For example:

```
sudo find src -type f \( -name 'luaotfload*.lua' -or -name 'fontloader*.lua' \) -exec cp {} /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload \;
```

### Update

Nothing's ever easy. It turned out that the above is not enough for the loader specified in `luaotfload-status.lua` to be executed:

```lua
 ["notes"]={
  ["loader"]="fontloader-2021-05-16.lua"
 },
```

When Lua engines tries loading `fontloader-2021-05-16.lua`, it delegates the task of searching the file to the `kpathsea` library. The latter either takes a look at the `ls-R` file to find the location, or starts complicated search inside your home directory. Since `fontloader-2021-05-16.lua` has a date in the name, it's not in the `ls-R` file and the search fails.

The right solution is to just copy `luaotfload` into your home directory:

```
mkdir -p ~/.texlive2021/texmf-var/tex/luatex/luaotfload
find src -type f \( -name 'luaotfload*.lua' -or -name 'fontloader*.lua' \) -exec cp {} ~/.texlive2021/texmf-var/tex/luatex/luaotfload \;
```